# splitter between fragments enables the user to resize it

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I apply this view ,I want to have 2 fragments horizontal with splitter that enables the user to resize fragments.

Example image at this link 
http://s22.postimg.org/iwfdop9ld/Untitled.jpg

Thanks in Advance.